# Get Normalized Location of Mouse in Figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to get current mouse position of mouse through `'WindowButtonDownFcn'` given below is my code :

```
   f = figure(1);
   set(f,'WindowButtonDownFcn',@mouselocation)
   uiwait(f)
    function mouselocation(source,callback)
        get(source,'CurrentPoint')
    end
```

When I click I do get the current position of the mouse but they are not normalized I tried:

```
 get(source,'CurrentPoint','units','normalized')
```

but It seem to give me an error that

> Too many input arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `hgconvertunits` to convert between the figure's (or any graphic object's) current units and normalized units.

```
pt = hgconvertunits(source, [get(source, 'CurrentPoint') 1 1], ...
                    get(src, 'Units'), 'Normalized', source);
pt = pt(1:2);
```

Alternately, you can simply change your figure's `Units` to `Normalized` and then the `CurrentPoint` will be returned in normalized units automatically.

```
fig = figure('Units', 'Normalized');

get(source, 'CurrentPoint')
```